# How to import a config file into multiple files in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a nodeJs app which uses a sysconfig.ts file to store some system info etc. In javascript i could require this file in any modulei like via

```
const config = require('../../config/sysconfig')
```

this works for the first file, but if i try to do this in a subsequent file get the following error

> TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'config'.

Ok the simple fix is to call the config different in everyfile but i dont think this is the best solution for this problem.
Here is what my config file looks like

```
module.exports = {
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'port': '8080',
    'portSecure': '443',
    'tokenlife': '5min'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
const config =  {
    host:"127.0.0.1",
  port: "8080",
  portSecure: "443",
  tokenlife: "5min"
  }

export default config;

// and import like this
import config from "./yourconfigpath/configFile"
```

Comment: Thanks that did the job, i also found another way by adding export{} at the beginning of any module that needed  the const config = require('../../config/sysconfig')